# subsetting a dataframe based on conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

need your help. I am new to this so just testing out screening strategies and trying out some code. I have a dataframe in R with prices of 108 stocks over 6 months.I wanted to select only those stocks where simple moving average is greater than just the mean of price of those stocks. I have the following code to calculate mean and SMA:

```
library(TTR)
library(quantmod)
library(FinancialInstrument)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(stats)
library(tseries)
#Load Systematic investor toolbox for helpful functions
setInternet2(TRUE)
con = gzcon(url('https://github.com/systematicinvestor/SIT/raw/master/sit.gz', 'rb'))
    source(con)
close(con)

tickerlist <- "funds.csv"  #CSV containing tickers on rows
startDate = as.Date("2004-01-13") #Specify what date to get the prices from
maxretryattempts <- 5 #If there is an error downloading a price how many times to retry

#Load the list of ticker symbols from a csv, each row contains a ticker
stocksLst <- read.csv("funds.csv", header = F, stringsAsFactors = F)
stockData <- new.env() #Make a new environment for quantmod to store data in
nrstocks = length(stocksLst[,1]) #The number of stocks to download

#Download all the stock data
for (i in 1:nrstocks){
    for(t in 1:maxretryattempts){
            tryCatch(
                    {
                               if(!is.null(eval(parse(text=paste("stockData$",stocksLst[i,1],sep=""))))){


                                    break
                            }


                        cat("(",i,"/",nrstocks,") ","Downloading ", stocksLst[i,1] , "\t\t Attempt: ", t , "/", maxretryattempts,"\n")
                        getSymbols(stocksLst[i,1], env = stockData, src = "yahoo", from = startDate, auto.assign=T)
                    }
                            , error = function(e) print(e))
        }
}

bt.prep(stockData,align='remove.na')

price = stockData$prices

SMA_price <- apply(price[,1:108], 2, SMA, n=120)
Mean_price <- apply(price[,1:108], 2, mean)
```

'price' is the dataframe which has all the prices. Here is a preview of what it holds:

```
head(price[,1:108])
           ABA.NZ ACY.NZ AIA.NZ AIR.NZ ALF.NZ AOR.NZ ARG.NZ ATM.NZ AUG.NZ
2013-12-19    6.0      5   3.60   1.63   0.04   0.01   0.90   0.77   0.75
2013-12-20    6.3      5   3.48   1.64   0.04   0.01   0.90   0.75   0.75
2013-12-23    6.3      5   3.55   1.62   0.05   0.01   0.92   0.80   0.75
2013-12-24    6.3      5   3.57   1.62   0.05   0.01   0.92   0.80   0.75
2013-12-25    6.3      5   3.57   1.62   0.05   0.01   0.92   0.80   0.75
2013-12-26    6.3      5   3.57   1.62   0.05   0.01   0.92   0.80   0.75
```

Any idea how I make this work?

Thanks!!!

Comment: My doubt is that your `SMA_price` is a matrix having the same dimensions as `price[,1:108]` while `Mean_price` is just a vector of values, 1 for each column.  When you are comparing both, there will be TRUE or FALSE in each column.  What would be the condition to select the column?

Comment: Yes that's correct! The condition to fulfil is the following: if SMA_price > Mean_Price then create a new subset with just those stocks that fulfill the condition

Comment: I did understand the condition, Suppose, you are comparing numbers, say column 1 (1:5 >3), you get 3 FALSE and 2 TRUE for that column.  If the condition is all the rows for a particular column of `SMA_price` is greater than `mean_price` for that column, it is possible.

Comment: Please accept my apologies didn't follow the first time around. I now see my mistake that I made earlier when putting the question. Essentially, what will happen is that, for a particular stock (e.g. ABA.NZ), the SMA_price matrix will only look at the 120th row of the matrix and compare with the ABA.NZ from Mean_price matrix and then execute the condition of subsetting the SMA_price matrix into a new one.

Comment: If I understand correctly, `Price[SMA_price[120,] >Mean_price,]` work?

Comment: yes, the condition works! thanks so much! But it is not quite what I was looking for. But that is my mistake. I will have a fiddle around. Thanks so much for the quick solution!

Comment: If you don't mind, could you explain what you are looking for? Thanks.